# Configure key mapping consisting of keyboard shortcut and a mouse click in IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, keymapping

I am using Intellij 13.1.5  running on a Mac (Mavericks).

My frustration is,  I am trying to re-configure the 'Navigate -> Declaration' mapping to the 'CTRL Button1 Click' key combination

- I have tried doing this using the user-interface - but it cannot recognise my attempt to Map the 'Ctrl' + Button1 Click' combination - as it is a combination of the **keyboard AND trackpad** usage.

Is there a way to set this by:

- Editing the configuration file these mappings are persisted to on the disk?
- Some other option within Intelij?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set keyboard/mouse combo shortcuts from *Settings/Keymap*. You just have to choose *Mouse shortcut* option.

1. Left Click on a command in Keymap section of the settings
2. Choose Add **mouse** shortcut (not add keyboard shortcut)
3. Hold down Ctrl and click with touchpad (or mouse) on the mouse icon

---

Here is also an alternative solution which involves directly modifying the configuration file:

1. Remap the shortcut to any other key (it does not matter which) and save preferences
2. Go to `$HOME/.IntelliJIdea[X]/config/keymap` (or `~/Library/Preferences/IntelliJIdea[X]/keymaps` on Mac). There should be XML file which contains only your modified keybindings (and therefore the command you remapped in step 1 should be there)
3. Change mapping of the command to whatever you want

Example content of the XML file in question (this should translate to Ctrl + Button 1, just change the action id to the id of your command):

```
<keymap version="1" name="Default copy 0" parent="$default">
  <action id="EditorCloneCaretAbove">
    <keyboard-shortcut first-keystroke="control B" />
    <mouse-shortcut keystroke="button1" />
  </action>
</keymap>
```

Comment: Thank you very much  - your suggestion of adding a mouse shortcut was extremely effective!

Comment: I tried to follow the same process with IntelliJ 14.1 and it doesn't seem to be storing the keymap customizations in the same place. Any idea where to find it?

Comment: @MattPassell Have you tried the second solution (mouse shortcut) it seems better than messing around with configuration files (first solution)? I'll try to update the first solution for IntelliJ 14 later this evening

Comment: Oops! Great point! I was foolishly working through your answer depth-first rather than breadth-first and got hung up on trying to find the settings file. The second set of instructions _did_ work for me. I'd recommend moving them up to be the first set in the answer, with the file editing only as a fallback. By the way, for IntelliJ 14 on a Mac, the file is stored in `~/Library/Preferences/IntelliJIdea14/keymaps`. See [the JetBrains help page](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/configuring-keyboard-shortcuts.html#d1688647e18547) for more details.

Comment: @MattPassell Done. I've moved up the better solution and included the path to configuration location in OS X in the answer. Thanks!

Comment: @BohuslavBurghardt Is there another location that this file may be? It exists in my AndroidStudio directory but not my IntelliJIDEA directory.

Comment: Still works 10 years after. Good job, Jetbrains